# Do I really have to walk to hatch my egg?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is walking the only option to hatch eggs? Will they also hatch if I drive by car, train or bycicle?

Answer (score 0):

Walking is the only way, if you go too fast it won't count the distance so it won't progress.